# Why does (1,5 - 1) * 2 equal to 8?

Tags: javascript

I know that in JS point is a decimal mark and I see that there's a comma between `1` and `5`, but why does `(1,5 - 1)` equal to `4` and what happens with `1,` in the beginning of the state

Comment: `1,5` is not one number. It's actually three things: the number `1`, a comma and the number `5`. So: `(1,5 - 1)` = `(1, 5 - 1)` = `(1, 4)` and the `1` is thrown away so the result of this expression is `4`.

Comment: [JavaScript Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use 1.5 but use 1,5

Comment: @MinhViet: Some languages use `,` as decimal separator. OP was probably curious how/why the expression still produced a result.

Comment: @MinhViet, I was solving some js-knowledge tests when i got the task.

Comment: @Jesper, That's exactly what I described in question. I want to know why `1` is thrown away from `(1, 4)`. I mean it is obvious that `(1, 5 - 1)` equal to `(1, 4)`. The point is why `(1, 4)` equals to `4`

Comment: It is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). By itself it's not useful, but it is useful, for example, to initialize multiple variables in a `for` statement.